# Filter out a list of strings

Tags: c, string

Given a list of strings such as `[boo,koo,kool]`

You try to filter out the characters that occur in all strings and further you filter out characters that occur equal number of times so in the case above you would return `oo`

In my approach i was thinking of first making a struct for all unique letters in the first string and keep a count of them and then do a compare with every other string. i think it might be a overkill in terms of run time. can anyone suggest better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a struct of sorts to use, its the type 'char' which stores -128 to 128 values.  Perhaps an array of ints for each word would do the trick, where you index the array with the char you have found in the string.

```
#define NUMWORDS 10  // assuming 10 words in list


int CountOfChars[NUMWORDS][256];

for each string n in list
{
for each char c in string n
{
     CountOfChars[n][c]++;
}
}
```

THEN analyze each CountOfChars array to find the counts >=2
You can use a loop like this:

```
char SetFlag;

for each char c in the system // a - z, A - Z
{
     SetFlag = 0;
     if (CountOfChars[0][c]>1)
     {
     for each string n in list except the first word 
           {
            if (CountOfChars[n][c]>1)
               SetFlag = c;
            else
               SetFlag = 0;
           }
     }
     if (SetFlag)
         printf("%c",SetFlag);  // prints a char found twice in all words

}
```

I have left this as psuedocode as it sounds like homework, hope this gets you started

Comment: Probably 2 x o(n^2) ... not very efficient at all.  But perhaps a good base pad, as you consider alternatives, like stacks, etc.  It depends if your 'question' can have mutable parameters (ie variable number of words, and different chars in the words etc), or is locked in and never changes

Comment: also in my problem i am not only considering cases where char equals two for example in string abcc bacc xcc i would return a cc

I am actually having trouble converting a char array in to list of struct for each unique character and it's count

Comment: @user2733436 if you post your struct - Edit your question perhaps - then we can comment and help you use it effectively.  Although a struct is overkill, you may like to explore the option

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using `TRIES`. something relevant: [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)

For example consider your given scenario:

```
+1  +2  
 b   k  
  \  |  
   \ | 
     o +3          ----|  
     |                 |  ==> this has contiguous max frequency.
     o +3          ----|
     |
     l +1
```

Since your array has only three string and count of contiguous string is 3. Therefore answer will be `oo`

Comment: Looks complicated but very interesting :)

Comment: It's not very complicated. You can find the details and implementation in the shared link. :p